# ($VersionNumber < 6) Cropping an exported image in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica

[image]

This is an animation I made using *Mathematica*. As can be seen by highlighting the image, the margins at both the left and right sides are too wide. I don't want to have to submit the image to another program just for the cropping, so what do I do to eliminate the whitespace?

Looking at the documentation, `ImageMargins` and `ImageRegion` would have been good except that they only apply to the front end. So, what do I do?

Comment: Why do you need to use version 5?   Is it because you don't have a newer version or because the program in only compatible with v5?  (In the latter case we might be able to come up with a fix more easily.  I don't think many people have v5 installed, so it'll be more difficult to get a non-guess v5 answer)

Comment: @Szabolcs: Because at the time I asked this question, all I had was version five. Now, I have access to a computer with version 8, but it isn't mine. The computer I am now using only has version five. So yes, I'm still interested.

Comment: @JM I didn't realize you posted the question in September.  My guess answer is that you might be able to use something like `PlotRegion -> {{0.1, 0.9}, {0.1, 0.9}}`.  My guess is based on doing ``Get["Version5`Graphics`"]; Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRegion -> {{.1, 0.9}, {0.1, 0.9}}]`` in version 8.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would try the `PlotRangePadding` option to your `Plot` function.  If the expression is already rasterized, you can try something like this:

```
imagelist /. Raster[a_, rest___]:> Raster[Take[#, {10, -10}]& /@ a, rest]
```

This should chop 10 pixels off either side. The image processing tools in V7 are quite nice and if you are able, I think you'd find the upgrade a very worthwhile investment.

Comment: `PlotRangePadding` is new as of Mathematica version 6, sad to say.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will possible find useful these two articles (although the first is for *Mathematica* 6 and the second is for v.7):

[Exporting Pixel-Perfect Graphics in Mathematica](http://stoney.sb.org/wordpress/2008/09/exporting-pixel-perfect-graphics-in-mathematica/)

and

[Pixel-perfect Graphics, Revisited](http://stoney.sb.org/wordpress/2008/11/pixel-perfect-graphics-revisited/).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`PlotRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Built-inFunctions/GraphicsAndSound/AdvancedOptions/PlotRegion.html) option.

Here is an example:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRegion -> {{0.1, 0.9}, {0.1, 0.9}}]
```

I tested this in v8 after doing `` <<Version5`Graphics` ``

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It is worth to note that the `PlotRegion` option accepts negative and out-of-`PlotRange` values: `Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10},Axes->False,Frame->True,PlotRegion->{{-0.1,1.1},{0,1}}]`.